# Hash password in my program

Tags: c#, hash, passwords

I have a password protection in my program. I have a txt file on my website(example.com/pass.txt). Everything is OK. The program will check if the password is correct, and if the password is the same as in the txt file, the program say "OK! Password is ok". But. What i need to do, if i put the HASH password in to the txt file? For example in my txt file on example.com/pass.txt will be - 1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72. How the program can check this? There is a security problem, because somebody can have my password very easy, if it's not with HASH.

So what i need.
My program need to check the "hash" password from my website. If the hash password will be correct, the program says "OK! Password is correct". As i said before. my program is ok, but for now i don't have a password in hash, so it's easy to know my password.. could you help me? I just need how to check the hash password. :)

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question for you. When you are to check password, you just calculate its hash and compare it to one in that .txt file, that's pretty much it. Please, clarify your question if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Web servers will serve text files so someone will be able to download your password "database".

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to apply hash to given password on your side. Computed hash is what you need to find in pass.txt;

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store your hashed password in the text file. You should use a database instead. But please, for all that is holy, salt your hashes. There are thousands of cracked hashes already on the internet, and just Googling the hash you gave as an example turns up the word `pass`.

First you want to salt your password.

1. Generate the salt (take a look at `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`)
2. Salt your hash
3. Store the salt and store the salted hash

To verify

1. Hash the attempted password
2. Use your previously stored salt to salt the hash we just created
3. If the salted hash we just made matches the one that's stored, then log the user in